# How to convert a std::string into a different class of string?

Tags: c++

I read data from a file and I wanted to use on of its values in a function. This is a custom function, I am programming TOOLKIT for Creo Parametric.

Well, that function is expecting a 'xrstring' but I have a std::string.

How to I convert one into another?

I've tried writing xrstring test_var = xrstring(std_var);

And it doesn't work.

```
//definition of xrstring

typedef const char          *xrstring;
#define xstringuninit   ((xrstring) 2)
#define xstringnil      ((const char *) 1)
#define xwstringnil     ((const wchar_t *) 1)
#define xwstringuninit     ((const wchar_t *) 2)

//definition of pfcCreateStringParamValue

pfcParamValue_ptr        pfcCreateStringParamValue (xrstring Value);
```

error C2664: 'pfcParamValue_ptr pfcCreateStringParamValue(xrstring)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'xrstring'

Comment: Probably `xrstring test_var(std_var.c_str());`

Comment: You can't implicitly convert a `std::string` object to a pointer to `char` (const or not), and you have never been able to do that. You need to explicitly do it using the [`c_str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) function. This should be well known to all who studied a little.

Comment: Note that `xrstring test_var = std_var.c_str();` the `test_var` is only valid for as long as the life span of `std_var`, and only as long as `std_var` is not modified.  If `test_var` needs to live longer than that, `std::strdup` will make a copy, but then you need to `std::free` that memory when done with `test_var`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, c_str work. However, if std_var has special characters, test_var becomes some weird characters. How can I fix this?

Comment: *This is a custom function, I am programming TOOLKIT for Creo Parametric.* -- I can't think of a single "toolkit" that has their own string type to not be able to take a `char *` to a buffer of characters.  The `std::string::c_str()` function provides such a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xrstring` you speak of is `const char *` or a C-style string.

`std::string` comes with a convenient function to convert a `std::string` to C-style string - `std::string::c_str()`

Hence, here is the right way to do what you want to do:

```
xrstring test_var = std_var.c_str();
```

Also, there does not exist a direct `const char *` to `std::string` cast. The Standard Library string is not a mere pointer-to-char. It contains other information like string-length as well.

I personally would recommend you to declare `xstring` as a class if you want to do a conversion like `xrstring test_var = xrstring(std_var);`, and make a suitable constructor for the conversion.

Comment: Thanks, that works. However, if std_var has special characters, test_var becomes some weird characters. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show us one such case here (a std_var with special characters and what it's test_var looks like)?

Comment: I was trying to write in a logfile to check if I was retrieving data correctly from my .csv file. I kept getting weird results whenever I started my program. I figured out through my notepad++ that it was sometimes encoding in ANSI and sometimes UTF-8.

In ANSI It comes out good "Construção", in UTF-8, instead of a "çã" i have 2 black rectangles with xE7 and xE3  (can't copy it here). When I use this string in my program, I get this: ඗翷.

Comment: I guess, you might want to take a look at `wchar_t` and `wstring` to get the Unicode support in C++ and define `typedef const wchar_t *xrstring;` instead. I am not aware of any implementations of C++ where normal `char` and `string` are interpreted as UTF-8 by the compiler.